# Is there a better way to get AD group members for a given list of AD group ObjectGUIDs?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of ObjectGUID's (49 of them) stored in a CSV, and I'm outputting a CSV which contains a listing of all members of those groups in the following format: "LastName, FirstName" , "AD Group Name"
I have it working (most of the time; sometimes I get IOException errors from the Add-Content cmdlt), but it is very slow (takes ~30 minutes for 8000 members). I don't have a lot of experience with Powershell , but I feel like there is a better/more efficient way of doing this. Any ideas on how to make this more efficient?

Note: I use the "-Server" switch because I actually have to run this script across a couple different domains, so the code I've pasted is duplicated twice in my original code, with a different CSV input, and a different domain passed to the "-Server" switch.

```
#read in CSV of ObjectGUIDs
$guids = Import-CSV .\ObjectGUIDs.csv

#loop through each AD group
foreach($group in $guids) {
    $group_name = Get-ADObject -identity $group.objectGUID -server myDomain
    $group_name = $group_name.Name

    #get list of users in current group
    $users = get-adgroupmember  -server myDomain -identity 
             $group.ObjectGUID | where {$_.objectclass -eq 'user'}

    #loop through each user of the current group
    foreach ($user in $users) {
        #get display name of current user
        $display_name = get-aduser -identity $user.objectGUID -server 
                        myDomain -properties DisplayName
        #build the current row
        $row =  ('"' + $display_name.DisplayName + '"' + ',' + '"' + 
                 $group_name + '"')
        add-content -path "C:\Path\to\output.csv"  -value $row
    }
}
```

As I said above, this usually works, but takes a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gathering data in a `[PSCustomObject]` and using `Export-Csv` only once should be much more efficient.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\27\SO_53946702.ps1

$guids = Import-CSV .\ObjectGUIDs.csv
$CsvFile = "C:\Path\to\output.csv"
$Server = myDomain

$CsvData = foreach($group in $guids) {
    $GroupName = (Get-ADObject -identity $group.objectGUID -server $Server).Name

    #get list of users in current group
    $users = Get-ADgroupMember  -Server $Server -Identity $group.ObjectGUID |
              Where-Object ObjectClass -eq 'user'

    foreach ($user in $users) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DisplayName = (Get-ADuser -Identity $user.objectGUID -server $Server -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName
            GroupName   = $GroupName
        }
    }
}
$CsvData | Export-Csv $CsvFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Also cache the result of `Get-ADUser` by users' SIDs for example, this can save some time because this code requests user details from AD each time it encounters a user in any group. Also this doesn't account for rtansient group membership - but TS didn't state it's needed.

Comment: Can you provide some example code of 'cache(ing) the result of Get-ADUser'? Is that somehow different than using each user's ObjectGUID to get their DisplayName? Also, what is transient group membership? I Googled it but nothing came up with that specific name.

Comment: To have @Vesper notice your comment, address him like I did with a leading `@`

Comment: @Vesper See my comment above.

Comment: @deano Transient group membership is a construction where Group1 has Group2 as its member, and Group2 has users in it, that are then evaluated as members of Group1 as well, but are not displayed in Group1's `Get-ADGroupMember` list. Caching is done via global object of type dictionary, you then do `if {dic[$_.samaccountname] -eq $null} {dic[$_.samaccountname]=Get-ADUser $_.objectGUID ...}` and then address `dic[$_.samaccountname]` instead of always calling `Get-ADUser`.

Comment: @LotPings Your version is running in about 25 minutes vs 30, so ~16.5% faster. I wish I understood Vesper's idea re: using a dictionary, but as I said in my post, I am not good with Powershell; if I even understood the logic behind his/her idea, I could then try to research how to do it. In any case, thx for help.